# "Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer machine name. This operation might require other privileges"

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to find running services in my network systems. I am able to get some but for some systems I am getting the error:

> "Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer machine name. This operation might require other privileges"

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("OPCGlobasysService",servername);
ServiceControllerStatus st = sc.Status;                

if (st.ToString().ToLower() == "stopped")
{
   labelControl4.Text = "Installed but stopped";
}

if (st.ToString().ToLower() == "running")
{
   labelControl4.Text = "Installed and started";
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well yes, it's not a privilege you hand out to all and sundry is it? You need to give the account you are running as enough privileges on the remote system, or remotely access with an account that does have the privilege.

Answer (score 1):

You should impersonate a user that has the relevant access before making the call.